# How to read data which is duplicate only once in Apache Nifi?

Tags: oracle11g, google-bigquery, apache-nifi

I am currently working on migrating data in batches from Oracle database to Bigquery.

I have setup the processors as follows: `ExecuteSQL`, `ConvertAvroToJson`, and `PutBigqueryBatch`

The data is read from oracle and being put in Bigquery successfully. However, I noticed that there are lot of duplicates of same data. I looked through how the data is being queued in Apache Nifi. I can see that there are lot of duplicate for the same data from Oracle. I tried to use `DetectDuplicate` processor but I wasn't successful.

Is there any way I can fix my problem with some sort of programming or is there any processor for my requirement?

Comment: Since BQ doesn't have a unique index like Oracle I suggest to clean the data in Oracle before shipping it to BQ it'll save you cost and be more efficient

Comment: The problem is not duplicate data in Oracle (If the Oracle has a row twice then I would want that in Bigquery like table replication). The problem is, if I do 'Select * from Table', ExecuteSQL is queuing the same table data several times until I stop the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, in the `Scheduling` section, the `ExecuteQuery` was set to execute every 0 seconds.

Setting it to higher value made it execute to the time I gave in the property.

Comment: If your table has a column that is strictly increasing (ID or timestamp for example), you can use QueryDatabaseTable instead of ExecuteSQL. The former (when you set the Max Value Column property to the ID or timestamp) will only grab "new" rows when it executes.

Comment: Does it put strain on the database? That is a good CDC solution if I do some scheduling with it.

Comment: You may not want to schedule QueryDatabaseTable for 0 seconds either, as it will issue queries against the database as fast as it can (even if no rows are returned). You'd want to schedule it for as often as you want to grab new rows (maybe once a minute or something?)

Comment: Yeah, I have set it up to issue query every midnight since data is gets inserted into already existing rows for my case.